# How can I reset password on Windows 2012 without knowing it?

Tags: password, windows-server-2012

I'm running virtual environment w/ Windows 2012 for about a month and Windows just reminded me that I should change my password soon as otherwise it'll expired. I don't remember my current password as it was saved into my configuration file. needless to say I *AM* an Administrator of the box and I do have administrative privilege (including changing password). I've tried going through Management but Windows suggests that I do it only using CTRL+ALT+DEL (the only problem with that it will ask me for my current password and once again I dont know it). I Googled but so far I found bunch of 3rd party utilities that supposedly deals with it, yet I'm looking for a bit kosher way aka "Microsoft approved / recommended" (if you will).

how shall I proceed?

Comment: You have admin priviledges? THen you can RESET the password.

Comment: that's like not saying anything, I _AM_ an Administrator of this box, as I said earlier credentials are saved in my file, so I never had to type it (hence not remembering it).

Comment: why am I getting down vote? who ever is down that should explain in comment "what's wrong?"!

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I updated my question.

Comment: @alexus: do you really think there would be a way to get the password for an account?  That would not be a very secure operating system.

Comment: @GregAskew, I'm not looking for a password itself, I'm asking how can I reset it without knowing password, what's the proper way of doing it if you don't remember it. So far I just disabled "Maximum password age" from 42 days to 0 (which will not make it expire).

Comment: What configuration file are you talking about? If your password is in a file why don't you just read the file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're still logged in when you forgot your password, then you can reset it in Computer Management.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, type **Computer Management** into the search box, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you are using Server Core, start `compmgmt.msc` from the command prompt.
   [image]
2. On the left pane, expand **System Tools**, then expand **Local Users and Groups**, then click on **Users**.
   [image]
3. In the center pane, right-click on **Administrator** and then click **Set Password...**
   [image]
4. Click **Proceed**.
   [image]
5. Change your password.
   [image]

Comment: do you know more about step #4, which irreversible loss of information is it referring too? what exactly am I loosing?

Comment: @alexus That is answered in the screenshot in step 5.

Comment: OK, I don't really have any of that, so I think it's safe to proceed. Thanks for such a colorful diagram))

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried going through Management but Windows suggests that I do it
>   only using CTRL+ALT+DEL (the only problem with that it will ask me for
>   my current password and once again I dont know it)

alexus, don't take this personally but it's clear from your question and especially from the statement I quoted above that you aren't particularly skilled in this area. If you are currently logged on to the computer in question, and you are in the local Administrators group, and you have access to the local user accounts, then you should simply change your password from the Computer Management MMC console. There's nothing wrong with doing it from there and it doesn't require you to know the current password.

The suggestion that you change your password by pressing CTRL+ALT+DEL is only a suggestion, it's not a requirement. Both methods accomplish the same thing.

Comment: right I do consider this as one of my options, the only con with that it's saying is there will be some data loss, and I'm not sure which data is it referring too, I do _NOT_ want to loose any of my data that's for sure.