# Username and password default in win server 2012 on hp proliant

Tags: windows-server-2012, hp-proliant, password

I've installed the Windows Server 2012 Standard (WSS2012) via Intelligent Provisioning (IP) on HP Proliant (dl380e gen8). In any moment I was asked for an username or password, both onto IP steps and WSS2012 steps. After full instalation in the initial screen I was warned to change my password and in the next restart It will be mandatory. I don't know the password and username, in the HP server box has an user and pass but not match. It will be necessary reinstall the system (another)? Some one passed by this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2012 R2, by default, installs with a user named `Administrator` with a blank password and forces you to change it at first boot.  That sounds like what you ran into, so try that.

Failing that, it's not hard to reset a Windows password with a boot disk any number of ways, including by copying cmd.exe to utilman.exe and then using the ease of accessibility tool (which is now cmd.exe) to open up a command prompt with administrative rights.

Comment: I tried, but nothing. As I was logged in I was able to change the password setting on the users [manually](http://serverfault.com/questions/466464/how-can-i-reset-password-on-windows-2012-without-knowing-it?rq=1). However, now I have problems with certificates, for intance, remote connection.